# fetching data out of a database sqlite3 nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite

I've got the following code. In dataArray I need the result of a query. Where to write that query and with what syntax? Does anybody have an example of fetching data out of a database using this format?

```
app.get('/products',function(req,res) {
var dataArray = [];
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'});
res.end(JSON.stringify(dataArray)); 
});
```

Comment: why not use an npm module like  this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3

Comment: I do use exactly that npm module. But I don't know how to use it to get data out of an database. I've only used it to insert it into a database...